# Intent to a preferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

I was wondering if it is possible to intent to a specific preferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="first_preferencescreen">
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="wifi enabled"
        android:title="WiFi" />
<PreferenceScreen
        android:key="second_preferencescreen"
        android:title="WiFi settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="prefer wifi"
            android:title="Prefer WiFi" />
    ... other preferences here ...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'd like to intent to "second_preferencescreen", is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up your `<PreferenceScreen>` items into separate resource files. Say `preferences1.xml` and `preferences2.xml`. In general, Android xml can only have one root (top level) tag.

Then create FirstPreferenceActivity and SecondPreferencesActivity that extend [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

Then call `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences1)` or `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences2)` in `onCreate` as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity).

Once you've got that setup, then you can call `startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstPreferencesActivity.class))` or `startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPreferencesActivity.class))`.